# Problem when my React App is put on the web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, production, filezilla

I have created my React App, `npm run build` ... Put my file in filezilla, 
but the problem is that I have this error

```
Not Found
The requested URL /main was not found on this server.
```

when I go to a page other than https://clickswinner.alwaysdata.net

What are you propose ?

Comment: how is anyone supposed to know how to help without any code? generally that error would mean the route is not defined on the server.

Comment: also that link looks spammy, don't expect many ppl to click it in an effort to help. rather, submit your server code for the route in question.

Comment: Yes, but it works locally. And what part of the code do you want ?

Comment: @Matt0o: Can you share the server name in which you have hosted your files...

Comment: @HolyMoly alwaysdata https://www.alwaysdata.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a .htaccess file and put it at root of your server

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend

Here is an article about how to fix 404 issues for Filezilla
https://medium.com/@christine_tran/deploying-a-simple-react-application-using-ftp-filezilla-dreamhost-1e5ff6b8abd6